# Cognitive Services API 401 on authorization

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use the Cognitive Services API (Text Translator), I've got an Azure subscription and have obtained a subscription id.

Using the examples from MS I pass the subscription id through to https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken using a POST. The response is a 401.

I've checked the subscription id, tried the interactive page but it all returns the same, I've only just setup the subscription so it shouldn't be invalid.

Any ideas on what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was wrong, I mistakenly used the subscription id from the Azure API that I'd setup, I actually needed to use the Key from the 'Keys' option in 'Resource Management'.